# Is it possible to add any IP address as exit node?

Tags: exit-relays

The IP addresses of Exit nodes are well known for anyone who is interested in it.

Is it possible to setup an exit node so its IP address isn't published in the list of Tor exit nodes?

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to add any IP address as exit node?

Anyone can add an exit node to the network, regardless of their IP address.

> Is it possible to setup an exit node so its IP address isn't published in the list of Tor exit nodes?

This is not possible. All relays, whether or not they're exits, are listed in the consensus. This is what clients and relays use to connect and authenticate to each other.